# OpenCart отобразить данные после заказа

Tags: php, sql, opencart

В общем, после заказа, попадаю на страницу index.php?route=checkout/success, где показывается сообщение "ваш заказ №3113" сформирован, бла-бла-бла.

Мне в этом сообщения нужно вывести "Имя заказчика" и "Email заказчика", мол "name" вам отправлено письмо на ваш "email". Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вывести в шаблоне этой страницы имя заказчика и его email. Шаблон вроде находится в `/catalog/view/theme/theme_name/template/common/success.tpl`. Имя заказчика туда точно передается, а вот передачу email возможно придется добавить в контроллере `/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php`

Comment: @Рашен-Беар, да, я знаю про шаблон, там же мне и нужно вывести эти данные.
А в какой переменной это имя находится? В массиве $data? Так он же обнуляется, по идее

Comment: В какой переменной оно находится - нужно смотреть в контроллере

Comment: Один из топорных вариантов - уж коли в контроллере есть номер заказа, то по нему найти нужный заказ ведь не проблема, а там уже и все данные нужные подтянуть.

Answer (score 0):

Если покупатель оформляет заказ без регистрации, кака гость то эти данные хранятся в сессии

```
$this->session->data['guest'];
```

Но имейте ввиду что перед выводом страницы success сессия $this->session->data['guest'] очищается. Чтобы это исправить нужно удалить эту строку в контроллере success.php

```
unset($this->session->data['guest']);
```

или изменить условие очищения сессии.

Если с регистрацией, то там сложнее, будет интересно, расскажу.